# Face ID prompt delay when the app coming from background to foreground (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, touch-id, face-id, localauthentication

I'm trying to lock my app when the app goes to background and the user can unlock the app when the app is in the foreground using biometric (FaceID/TouchID) authentication.

Here's a simple, reproducible example of my code:

```
import LocalAuthentication
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isUnlocked = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if isUnlocked { 

            // if the app is unlocked, app shows the text "Unlocked"
            Text("Unlocked")
                .font(.title)

                // app gets locked when the app goes to background
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
                    self.isUnlocked = false
                    print("locked the app")
                }

        } else { 

            // if the app is locked, app shows the text "Locked" and app should show prompt FaceID/TouchID prompt
            Text("LOCKED")
                .font(.title)

                // FaceID prompt shows when the app opens (from Non-running state)
                .onAppear(perform: authenticate)

                // FaceID prompt shows when the app coming from background to foreground
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
                    authenticate()
                    print("back inside the app")
                }
        }
        
    }
    
    // I use this to prompt the biometric authentication
    func authenticate() {
        let context = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?
        
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
            let reason = "We need to unlock your data"
            
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, authenticationError in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if success {
                        // app gets unlocked if biometrix authentication succeeded
                        self.isUnlocked = true
                    } else {
                        // authentication failed
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // no biometrics
        }
    }

}
```

When the user opens the app (from non-running state), FaceID prompt shows instantly without any delay. **BUT when the app comes from background to foreground, FaceID prompt takes around 5 seconds to show up.** I use the same function `authenticate()` to prompt the biometric authentication and Xcode console prints `"back inside the app"` instantly when the app comes from background to foreground.
 So what causes that FaceID delay?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: guessing, the async dispatch to set isUnlocked=true is called late for some reason. Maybe the SceneDelegate has to finish other business before this swiftUI part kicks in. For such an important feature i would observe and call from AppDelegate directly to set the isUnlocked state

Comment: Thanks Ol Sen. I’ve observed the isUnlocked state from SceneDelegate and now the FaceID prompt shows up without any delay.

Comment: yeah cool, chears, happy weekend.